# ListViewButtonClick in delphi

Tags: android, fragment

In **Delphi**, when I click a button on a **TListView**, nothing happens.

```
procedure TForm2.ListView1ButtonClick(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListItem; const AObject: TListItemSimpleControl);
begin
  ShowMessage(AItem.ToString + '  is clicked.');
end;
```

Also, the **OnItemClick** event doesnt work, either.

```
procedure TForm2.ListView1ItemClick(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
  ShowMessage(AItem.Text + ' ' +AItem.ButtonText + ' is clicked.');
end;
```

Comment: Could you please add which Delphi Version you are using?

Comment: Have you actually assigned the method to the event handler (either in the object inspector or in code)?

Comment: yes sure @dummzeuch

Comment: it is rad studio 10.1 @SebastianProske

Comment: Your edit completely changed the question for which answer was already provided. Please, don't do that. Instead post a new question. Your edit was rolled back to its previous state.

Comment: @TomBrunberg unfortunately i can not ask question anymore,thats why i edited my old question :( i am sorry but i dont have any other choice ((

Comment: And why can't you post a new q anymore? Anyway, changing an existing question for which answers have been provided, makes those answers look strange and is ofcourse not allowed.

Comment: unfortunately after 2 unvote to my question (as you can see), my "ask queston" is banned and i can not ask question until my question get positive feedback which seems unacceptable @TomBrunberg. i thought that if i edit my question , i can draw attention and got votes , because that was also chance getting rid of ban

Comment: The two downvotes you have got for this question do not prevent you from asking new questions. Anybody with at least one reputation (you have 24 now) can ask questions, unless they have been banned (for a limited time) because of bad behaviour. This is hardly the case. So just hit the  `Ask Question` button at the top.

Comment: :) when i hit **Ask Question** , i get the message : You have reached your question limit ; Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. How can I get out of a question ban?

The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were poorly received.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125905/discussion-between-afa-and-tom-brunberg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events fire as expected in a setup (using XE7) as follows:

1. File - New - Multi device application
2. TListView
3. TMemo
4. In *Structure* view select ListView1.ItemAppearance
5. In *Object inspector, Properties tab* select `ImageListItemRightButton` for property `ItemAppearance`
6. In *Structure* view select ListView1
7. In *Object inspector, Events tab* double click in the right column to create events for `OnButtonClick` and `OnItemClick`

Add code to populate the ListView

```
procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  LItem: TListViewItem;
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
    LItem.Text := IntToStr(i);
  end;
end;
```

Add code to the event handlers

```
procedure TForm3.ListView1ButtonClick(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem; const AObject: TListItemSimpleControl);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('ListView1ButtonClick: '+IntToStr(AItem.Index));
end;

procedure TForm3.ListView1ItemClick(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('ListView1ItemClick: '+IntToStr(AItem.Index))
end;
```

Run the project and see the result:

[image]

Comment: and what is Memo? is it like Toast in android that gives message?How can i declare Memo?

Comment: @Afa `TMemo` is a multiline edit box component. It is on the right side in my example where it shows the output of those `OnItemClick` and `OnButtonClick` events.

Comment: @androidmechanic please help

Comment: @Abhishek Patel please help